# Why to create a composite non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-optimization

I am trying to learn the basic indexing and query optimization techniques. I don't understand why should one create a composite non-clustered index. Let's consider a scenario as given below.

> Composite Non clustered Index on **ColumnA and ColumnB**  //Same sequence

I get a non-clustered index seek if I put the columnA alone or both toghther in where clause. So how columnB is contributing in index seek instead its eating up the while creating the B+ tree for the index. Would it make any difference if I drop the ColumnB from index?

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to selectivity. If ColumnA and ColumnB both have low selectivity and you are using both in where clause then it's probably worth to have a composite index. In you case it's not true because the index is used even if you query by ColumnA alone. But what happens when you drop ColumnB from the index? You save space of course. But to filter by ColumnB database engine needs to look up the rows in the clustered index. Now it depends on ColumnA's selectivity how many rows it needs to look up. If it's 3 then you are fine, if it's 3 million then you probably want to put the composite index back. Another thing to consider is how often are you filtering by both columns together? Always, mostly, rarely? In the end you need to test both scenarios which one fits better your performance and space requirements.